# Breaking long lines using latex with minted and pygments

Tags: minted, xml

Since Acrobat [obviously isn't able to convert XML to PDF from command line](https://superuser.com/questions/241206/are-there-any-command-line-options-to-adobe-acrobat-not-reader-for-conversion), I'm trying to achieve it using LaTeX.

I found the [`minted`](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/minted/) package doing a quite good (and simple) job since it uses [pygments](http://pygments.org/) to do the formatting and then puts back the formatted text into my document.

The package is working fine except when it comes to long lines in the input XML document that I'm trying to convert to PDF: the generated XML content in the PDF exceeds the right border of the document:
[image: screenshot]

Finally, to put in a question:
*Is there any way that I can tell pygments which page width to use for the output (and possibly keep a nice indent when it has to break a line, just like the Internet Explorer does when displaying XML files)?*

Yes, I *could* use the `listings` package instead, but with that one, AFAIK I have to define the keywords to get a reasonable highlighting for the XML content, right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`minted` can’t do that and since I have no idea how this line-breaking feature is implemented in `listings` there are no plans a the moment to add the feature. Sorry. :-(

My advice: for your situation, switch to `listings` (or break the lines manually).

Comment: Thanks for the clear statement. I think, I'll go for manual line breaking. Seems less work to me than configuring the `listings` package for my needs...

Comment: `minted` now has a `breaklines` feature.

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be no option for pygments to provide a line width. I would assume that it doesn't handles such thing by itself. If it can be done then only in its `latex` format driver.

Note that `minted`/`pygments` using `fancyvrb` to display the text while keeping `\` the macro character. Unfortunately `fancyvrb` can't break lines itself.
The `listings` package can do that, but doesn't support `\` as single escape character! :-(

Answer (score 1):

`minted` provides such break by breaksymbol `= =\small\carriagereturn`. This breaksymbol defines the symbol to break. So you can use this symbol where ever you want a break. For example, we use carriage return. You can adjust your XML strings by putting a carriage return the place you want a break.

```
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{dingbat}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}[breaklines, breaksymbolleft=\carriagereturn]{xml}
<?xml version="1.0"?>
abracadabraabracadabraabracadabr
aabracadabraabracadabraabracadab
raabracadabraabracadabraabracada
braabracadabra
<project name="Package tcolorbox" default="documentation" basedir=".">
<description>
Apache Ant build file (http://ant.apache.org/)
</description>
</project>
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```